# MongooseJS can't update numerical value

Tags: model, mongoose, updates

When using this `user.meta.logins.$inc();` I get this error in the console:

> Mongoose MongooseNumber#$inc / MongooseNumber#increment is deprecated.
>   Use Model.update() to get incrementation in v3 instead.

What I have beed doing is this (code is stripped down to the basic usage):

```
userSchema.methods = {
  userFind : function (user, pass, callback) {
    this.model('user').findOne({ 'username':user, 'password':pass }, callback); 
  }
}

var userModel = new model();
userModel.userFind(username, password, function(err, user) {
  user.meta.logins.$inc();
  user.meta.last_action = new Date();                   
  user.save();
});
```

This works just fine but since the deprecation is at hand, I want to use the proposed `Model.update()` method to update the user, however I can't make it happen.

I have tried doing `userModel.update()` and `user.update()` but in both cases I get errors. Maybe my syntax is wrong for the update.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `update` for this:

```js
userModel.update(
  { 'username': user, 'password': pass },
  { $inc: { logins: 1 }, $set: { last_action: new Date() }},
  function(err, numAffected) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: That I have already tried, thank you. It yields this error:

`Object { } has no method 'update'`

Comment: I was assuming that `userModel` is your Model class for users, but this line has me confused: `var userModel = new model();`  You should be calling `update` on the object returned from a call like `mongoose.model('user', userSchema);` where you register the schema.

Comment: Yes, that is what I do, the line `var userModel = new model();` is just a wrapper that returns a model and a connection.

As you may see, I am calling a method for the Schema (`userModel.userFind`) and that works just fine, so my wrapper is returning the model and the connection just fine.

Comment: This is all messed up.  `userSchema.methods` defines methods on model instances so you should be defining `userFind` with `userSchema.statics` so that it appears on the Model itself.  And then you need to call `update` on the Model itself, not a Model instance.

Comment: Indeed, the Schema.methods and the Schema.statics was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So this this the issue and the solution:

When you define Schema.methods you have to create an instance of the model in order to use them:

```
var myModel = new Model();
myModel.mySchemaMethod();
```

which causes a problem since the Models own methods (eg. Model.update) are no longer accessible.

In this case the methods should be defined as static, therefore no instance is required and it all works just fine:

```
myModel.mySchemaStatic();
```